# Django Newbie ManyRelated Manager not Iterable Question

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm trying to create a product code (in the admin) by combining elements from two other fields - one of which is a ManyToManyField. I'd like to iterate through that field to find out if a specific product option has been chosen, and append a variation of it to that non-editable product code, like so:

```
class ShirtColorClass(models.Model):
    shirtcolor = models.CharField(_('Shirt Color'), unique=True, max_length=40)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.shirtcolor

class ShirtClass(models.Model):
    shirtmodel = models.CharField(_('Model of Shirt'), max_length=40)
    shirtclr = models.ManyToManyField(_(ShirtColorClass, verbose_name='Shirt Color'))
    shirtcode = models.CharField(_('Code for the shirt'), max_length=80, editable=False)
    #...10 more fields...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.shirtmodel
    def save(self):
        for item in self.shirtclr: #these are the lines I'm not sure how to do
            if 'Blue' in self.shirtclr:
                self.shirtcode = u'%s%s' % ('B', self.shirtmodel)
            else:
                self.shirtcode = self.shirtmodel
            super(ShirtClass,self).save()
```

At the moment I'm getting a ManyRelatedManager not Iterable message, so I know I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what... I apologize in advance for this being a stupid newbie question. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Try calling `.all()` on it.

Comment: ...so something like this:
    def save(self):
        for item in self.shirtclr.all():
            if item == 'Blue':
                self.shirtcode = u'%s%s' % ('B', self.shirtmodel)
            else:
                self.shirtcode = self.shirtmodel
            super(ShirtClass,self).save()

I can't quite get that to work...ShirtClass not iterable is the error. What am I doing wrong? Thank you once again.

Comment: I think we need to step back and find out what you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm trying to save a third field by concatenating the components of the first two...the only complication is that one of the first two is a ManyToManyField and I don't know the proper way to access its contents in this instance. Looking at what I typed at the top, I don't think I need a for loop there...when I've used Python before, "in" has done the work for me when looking through a list. However, "if 'Blue' in self.shirtcode.all()" doesn't seem to work for me. I keep thinking this shouldn't be a difficult thing to accomplish...but I'm missing something...

Comment: Perhaps instead of making it a real field you should make it a property. http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/models/properties/ http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/aug/18/django-tips-using-properties-models-and-managers/

Answer (score 2):

call `filter()`:

```
def save(self):
    if self.pk!=None:
        if self.shirtclr.filter(shirtcolor='Blue'):
            self.shirtcode = u'%s%s' % ('B', self.shirtmodel)
        else:
            self.shirtcode = self.shirtmodel
    else:
        self.shirtcode = ''
```

you can avoid `self.shirtcode = ''` by adding `default=''` into

```
shirtcode = models.CharField(_('Code for the shirt'), max_length=80, editable=False, default='')
```

Comment: Yes (and thank you for your answer...sorry I couldn't get back to you right away). If there was no existing instance, I got a "'ShirtClass' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used" error. If there was one, the Post would complete, but shirtcode would equal shirtmodel no matter what color I chose. Any ideas?

Comment: As for the exception - corrected the answer, should work now. As for the shirtcode being always equal to shirtmodel, are you sure it is exactly `'Blue'`, not for example `'blue'` or `'blue '`